# Хедер таблицы и скролл

Tags: html, jquery, css, angularjs, прокрутка

Подскажите, как сделать таблицу, что б хедер всегда был виден при прокрутке?

Использую *bootstrap*, *Jquery/angularjs*

Comment: Таблица - это обычный `<table>` или миллион `<div>`'ов (как это любят делать библиотеки для создания красоты)?

Answer (score 1):

Добавлять `position: fixed;` к нужному элементу во время скролла.
Для данного решения понадобиться jQuery.

```
var win = $(window);
var element = $('#someId'); //идентификатор элемента, который нужно сделать фиксированным
var height = 200; //лимит высоты, поиграйтесь со значением, пока не добъетесь подходящего вам
win.scroll(function(){
    if(win.scrollTop() >= height)
    {
        element.addClass('fixed');
    }
    else { element.removeClass('fixed'); }
});
```

и в css добавляем

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: И что тут может быть не понятного? Или тут развернутый ответ подразумевает собой все написать за него? Лучше бы глупые вопросы фильтровали. Человек ангуляр изучил, а об фиксированных элементах не знает.

Comment: Stack Overflow как раз нужен для того, чтобы делиться знаниями (в частности, чтобы автор вопроса наконец узнал о вышеупомянутых элементах). Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.

Comment: ладно, пусть будет по вашему, только вот на оригинальном stackoverfow за такой вопрос слили бы карму

Comment: Спасибо! Не могу не согласиться с вами, что данный вопрос плохо структурирован. Я лишь прошу, от части, [следовать рекомендациям](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/536/6): либо дать развернутый ответ, либо пройти мимо. Более того, если по вашему мнению вопросу не место на сайте, вы можете проголосовать против или воспользоваться сигналом тревоги. [Вопросы с отрицательной оценкой время от времени автоматически удаляются с сайта.](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/392/)